# reactjs for both web and mobile applications

Tags: reactjs

I need to develop the application which will be same for mobile app and web application. I was researching on reactjs. 
Can I convert my reactjs code for web-app to react native for mobile application? The way we do in ionic framework(angular)

Comment: I would also tag this question with react-native, I would say it's probably a no to your question. You need to refactor to make it work because you need to use the react-native components like Text and View.

Comment: There is also the possibility to use react-native-web which is one code base in React to be used on web and native app platform. But I would probably not going that route if you are new to the React world.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can definitely use cordova \ phonegap in order to create an app out of your website, which will make it hybrid but not native (suitable for most site types)
2. You cannot 'convert' or re-transpile your code to react-native. You have to re-build it using react native. It will be much easier ofcourse because you have a running react system, but still.

I would recommend trying the first option. Good luck!